# How to deselect a range after applying autofilter criteria in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, select, autofilter

I have a VBA subroutine that sorts a range using the AutoFilter method (Actually, it sorts multiple different ranges across different worksheets.  It also calls another subroutine, which in turn calls other subroutines, etc.).

Anyway, I've noticed the following weird issue:

When I run this subroutine (called from a button on yet another worksheet), it runs fine, and does everything that I want it to do.  However, after it has run it leaves the entire range that it's performed the AutoFilter.Sort on selected.

This is despite the fact that I haven't got a .Select anywhere in my code (I try to avoid using .Select as much as possible).

Furthermore, if I step through the code line-by-line using F8, this doesn't happen!  If I run the subroutine from within VBA using F5, it also doesn't happen!  It only seems to happen when the subroutine is called from the button click and allowed to run through uninterrupted.

Here's the relevant section of code that runs the Autofilter.Sort:

```
'Sort data on Production sheet
With Sheet07.AutoFilter.Sort
    .SortFields.Clear
    .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("P21:P54"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
        Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortTextAsNumbers    'Need to remove hard-coded cell reference
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

Has anyone come across this issue before?  Is there a simple way to fix it without using .Select?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I just executed it from a Form button, and an ActiveX button but the range is not left selected - I can see the region being selected, but then the selection goes back to the last selected cell. Do you have any other Autofilters in the code?

Comment: @paul bica
Yes, there are other Autofilters in the code.

There are another two segments of code immediately following the one shown above that do the exact same thing on another two different worksheets.  They behave in exactly the same way (i.e. range is left selected if called from the Form Button and left to run through uninterrupted, but not if run in VBA via F5 or stepped through line-by-line using F8).

Comment: @paul bica
I also have another subroutine that does exactly the same thing, except with the ActiveSheet instead of a specific sheet.  It does not exhibit this weird behaviour.